# How to provide a CLI for a GUI java swing application

Tags: java, console, console-application

What are the best practices to provide a CLI to an existing GUI java swing application.

For reading text fields I can use `console.readLine(); or InputStreamReader(System.in)`,
But my GUI is having radio buttons, checkboxes, comboboxes. So what are the alternatives in CLI for these components of GUI?

My GUI application is a wizard kind of, so I want to develop CLI which have same sequence of steps as GUI wizard. Are there any best practics for writing CLI application?

Is it good to use `Console class of java.io`? OR to use `sys.out.println()` incombination with `InputStreamReader(System.in`) for writing and reading to console?

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of CHARVA?  Might not be exactly what you are looking for, but seems promising.
http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/index.html